# Why Test.setMock() is not working in case of static resource?

Tags: apex, integration, httpcalloutmock, mock

Test.setMock() is not working

```
Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void setMock(System.Type, System.StaticResourceCalloutMock) from the type test
```

[image]

Source Code:

```
@isTest
private class AnimalsCalloutsTest {
    @isTest static  void testGetCallout() {
        // Create the mock response based on a static resource
        StaticResourceCalloutMock mock = new StaticResourceCalloutMock();
        mock.setStaticResource('GetAnimalResource');
        mock.setStatusCode(200);
        mock.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
        // Associate the callout with a mock response
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, mock);
        // Call method to test
        HttpResponse result = AnimalsCallouts.makeGetCallout();
        // Verify mock response is not null
        System.assertNotEquals(null,result, 'The callout returned a null response.');
        // Verify status code
        System.assertEquals(200,result.getStatusCode(), 'The status code is not 200.');
        // Verify content type   
        System.assertEquals('application/json;charset=UTF-8',
          result.getHeader('Content-Type'),
          'The content type value is not expected.');  
        // Verify the array contains 3 items     
        Map<String, Object> results = (Map<String, Object>) 
            JSON.deserializeUntyped(result.getBody());
        List<Object> animals = (List<Object>) results.get('animals');
        System.assertEquals(3, animals.size(), 'The array should only contain 3 items.');          
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any time you see this sort of error where a standard class appears to be missing methods, it is almost always caused by name shadowing. Double check that you do not have any variables nor classes named `Test`. If this issue is what blocks you currently, you should try to resolve the name shadowing first. Failing that, the workaround would be to instead reference `System.Test` instead of `Test`, which will disambiguate.